# FCK Editor customization

Tags: php, javascript, fckeditor

When we click on the anchor tag of fckeditor, we will obtain one pop up asking the anchor name.
I need to get same functionality for adding the footnote in my application.

Is it possible to customize the fckeditor in this way. Here I need to add one toolbar item 'say footnoe'. when we click on that appear a pop up.
where the anchor section code is written in fckeditor?

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about FCK editor or the Ckeditor?

You can extend CKeditor via plugins. Here is a tutorial http://www.voofie.com/content/2/ckeditor-plugin-development/

anchor code is in '\ckeditor\plugins\link\dialogs\anchor.js' (compressed)

source is in 'ckeditor\_source\plugins\link'.

Hope this helps.